# How to use setState() in React to blank/clear the value of an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

I am trying to clear an array, but I'm having trouble. 
`this.setState({warnErrorTypes:[]})`

I'm not sure if I am dealing with a race condition, or what the specific issue is, but I can see that the value of my array is consistently wrong in the case that I need to reset its value to [].

How does one replace an array that contains [1,2] with [] then subsequently [3] where the following are true:

1. this.state.warnErrorTypes is an Array which starts out with []
2. Based on condition, 2 is pushed in Array
3. Based on condition, 1 is pushed in Array.
4. Based on condition, 3 is NOT pushed in Array
5. Pause. User interacts with UI
6. Array is blanked: `this.setState({warnErrorTypes:[]})`
7. Based on condition, 2 is NOT pushed in Array
8. Based on condition, 1 is NOT pushed in Array
9. Based on condition, 3 is pushed in Array.

The result of the logic above is always `[2,1,3]`, when I expect it to be `[3]`.

Comment: Could you provide an example showing the problem in a JSBin/jsfiddle?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/fogonthedowns/d7a1ddb28129c82fad0c

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`setState` gets aggregated and scheduled, it does not run atomic and immediate, so you can't just issue multiple setState() calls and expect things to work, you either have to wait for the state to update before updating it again, or use an instance variable.

Option 1:

```
doSomething() {
  this.setState({
    myarr: []
  }, () => { // called by React after the state is updated
    this.setState({
      myarr: [3]
    });
  });
}
```

This is fairly cumbersome and depending on what you're doing, mostly just bad code. The other option is to use a "real" instance variable that you send over as state at moments when you need to.

Option 2:

```
getInitialState() {
  this.mylist = [];
  return {
    myarr: this.mylist
  };
},

...

doSomething() {
  this.mylist = [];
  for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    this.mylist.push(i);
  }
  this.setState({
    myarr: this.mylist
  });
}
```

Remember that updating the state means you have changed an aspect of your component in a way that requires a rerender, so don't use setState for "intermediate" changes, i.e. changes where a render is not necessary, like clearing the array before refilling it (the state change is the new data, not the intermediate cleared state). Do that stuff separately, and only update the state once you're done.

Option 3:

You could also do this by taking out the state values, running your updates, and then rebinding, without ever building a persistent instance variable:

```
doSomething {
  const list = this.state.myarr;
  list.splice(0, list.length);
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    list.push(i);
  }
  this.setState({
    myarr: list
  });
}
```

The net effect is the same: you *only* update your UI when your data is in some stable configuration, so if you're calling `setState()` more than once between renders for the *same* state key, that's a problem: every `setState()` call may trigger a render "eventually", and consecutive `setState()` calls before that happens will override same-named-key updates if you don't wait for them to be processed first.

Comment: It's also possible to pass a function to `setState` which gets the current pending state as argument and should return a new state. That makes it easy to avoid multiple calls to `setState` clobbering each others values.

Comment: ''called by React after the state is updated" :p Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Option 3, as mentioned by Anders Ekdahl:

```javascript
  moo () {
    this.setState(state => ({
      myarr: []
    }));

    // ...

    if (weShouldAddAThree) {
      this.setState(state => ({
        myarr: [ ...state.myarr, 3 ]   // like push but without mutation
      }));
    }
  }
```

This pattern is useful if you need to refer to the previous existing state when you perform your state update.  I'm not sure if you really need the previous state in your example, but I will explain this pattern as if you did.

The merge operation we provide to `setState` is always applied asynchronously, at some point in the future, [at React's discretion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33613728/what-happens-when-using-this-setstate-multiple-times-in-react-component#comment71388883_33613918).  When the `setState()` function returns, our operation has not been applied, it has only been queued.

Therefore we should never use `this.state` in our state updater, because that might be out of date: an old copy of the state.  If we need to know the previous state, we should receive the `state` argument in the function we pass to setState, and use that.

Answer (score -1):

You can as well use this to clear array:

```
   this.state.your_array.length = 0;
   setState({your_array});
```