# Difference between way of importing mobx

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobx, mobx-react, mobx-utils

How does the following import make a difference?

> import { observer } from 'mobx-react/native'

instead of

> import { observer } from 'mobx-react'

## Additional Information

- React Native version: ~0.48.4
- React: 16.0.0
- mobx-formatters: 1.0.2,
- mobx-logger: 0.6.0,
- mobx: 3.3.1,
- mobx-persist: 0.3.4,
- mobx-react: 4.3.3

*Comment If any more information required*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobx-React uses a function called `unstable_batchedUpdates`.
This dependency comes from `react-dom` (browser) or `react-native` (mobile).
On your mobile device you have no dom so you can not use react-dom.
So when you import 'mobx-react/native' it uses the function from the react-native package.

See here:

https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react/blob/0e1cdc83bfb7e45a43aa9b8f23498d3c95943433/src/index.js

You can also see in `mobx-react` in your nodes modules folder, that the index.js (resolved when importing from 'mobx-react') gets the ReactDom as a dependency:

```
}(this, (function (exports,mobx,React,ReactDOM) { 'use strict';
```

While on the other hand importing from 'mobx-react/native', it gets reactNative as a dependency instead of the ReactDom:

```
}(this, (function (exports,mobx,React,reactNative) { 'use strict';
```

If you want to learn more about react batching updates read here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/33613918/2379376
- [https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/3b43f3190bbcc5d4cfe77dbc665e03b7b95d35b2/src/renderers/**tests**/ReactUpdates-test.js](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/3b43f3190bbcc5d4cfe77dbc665e03b7b95d35b2/src/renderers/__tests__/ReactUpdates-test.js)