# How to update state in react synchronously

Tags: reactjs, axios, setstate

```
onSave=()=>{
    if (this.state.intialValue<=0) {
        this.setState({errorIntialValue: true})
      }
      else
      {
      this.setState({errorIntialValue: false})
      }
      if (this.state.age>=25|| this.state.age<=-1) {
        this.setState({errorAge: true})
      }
      else{
        this.setState({errorAge: false})
      }
      if (this.state.rollNo<0) {
        this.setState({errorRollno: true})
      }
      else{
        this.setState({errorRollno: false})
      }
       if(!(this.state.errorIntialValue|| this.state.errorAge ||errorRollno)){    //have to 
                                                                    enter only if no error
    let newData={
            intialValue:this.state.intialValue,
            age:this.state.age,
            rollNo:this.state.rollNo
    }
    this.props.updateData(newData)
}
```

I have a onClick event onSave. If error is there in the form I'm setting the state of those to true.Since SetState is asynchronous,the value won't be updated to its state and is always undefined when it come to  `if(!(this.state.errorIntialValue || this.state.errorAge || errorRollno))` and it returns false. The code in if block will never get executed. 
I'm not able to find a proper way to achieve this.How can I do this?

Comment: You need not call setState for everychange, rather you can set the values in an updated object and call setState once at the end

Comment: It seems you would be better off using the functional version of `setState` and the callback to achieve this functionality

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings actually we can use callback with 'object' version of `setState()` too

Comment: @skyboyer Functional version because, OP is using state to compare. Callback is for a different use case

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings agree with you. Even if `onSave()` looks like click handler one day it can be called programmatically after `.setState` and thing will go out of sync

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use `unstable_batchedUpdates` as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52025835/3731501) to make state updates synchronous:

```
// this.state.foo === 0 here

ReactDOM.unstable_batchedUpdates(() => {
    this.setState({ foo: this.state.foo + 1});
});

// this.state.foo === 1 here
```

This method is not applicable here, the need for it indicates that there is a problem.

[The documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) suggests to use updater function if `setState` state depends on previous state, and use callback function if evaluated code depends on previously set state:

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater, callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous state, read about the updater argument below.

It's unclear from the code why temporary values (`errorIntialValue`, `errorAge`, `errorRollno`) should be stored in component state. They likely shouldn't and should be updated only once, something like:

```
if (errorIntialValue || errorAge || errorRollno) {
  // update the state with errors
} else {
  // update the state with data
}
```

Comment: I guess it's stored to state to highlight errors/display messages

Answer (score 0):

As @BoyWithSilverWings pointed out it's better to use functional version of `setState` to be sure we run checks on stable state. Otherwise in case when you call `this.onSave()` programmatically you might operate on old version of state.

Having that in mind we utilize callback goes second parameter as @estus gave a link to.

```
onSave=()=>{
    this.setState(currentState = > {
        errorIntialValue: currentState.intialValue<=0,
        errorAge: currentState.age>=25|| currentState.age<=-1,
        errorRollno: currentState.rollNo<0
    }, ({errorIntialValue, errorAge, errorRollno}) => {
       if([errorIntialValue, errorAge, errorRollno].some(isInvalid=> isInvalid)){    
          let newData={
               intialValue:this.state.intialValue,
               age:this.state.age,
               rollNo:this.state.rollNo
          }
          this.props.updateData(newData)
       } 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
await this.setState({ foo: this.state.foo + 1})
```