# React state is batched life cycle and non-event functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The `setState` functions are batched and final state is set by combining all the states in event handler functions. I am curios that multiple `setState` function calls are batched in life cycle methods or not. Similarly if the function is not an event handler, is batching happens or not.

Comment: Maybe ... ... ...

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10231#issuecomment-316644950 does this answer your question perhaps?

Comment: See also for TL;DR version, https://stackoverflow.com/a/52025835/3731501