# setState being called multiple times after await

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've written a test case in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oPRXxd#anon-login)

Run the test by clicking the button, then see the result from Browser Console.

You can see from the console log that even I called `setState` multiple times **before** `await`, it will only update the component once.

But if I call `setState` multiple times **after** `await`, it will update the component multiple times too.

Any idea why is this happening?

Code:

```
/*
 * A simple React component
 */
class Application extends React.Component {

  state = {
    value: 0
  }

  onClickHandler = (e) => {
    this.runAsyncFunc();
  }

  runAsyncFunc = async() => {
    console.log('BEFORE AWAIT');
    this.setState({ value: 1 });
    this.setState({ value: 1 });
    this.setState({ value: 1 });

    await setTimeout(()=>{}, 2000);

    console.log('AFTER AWAIT');
    this.setState({ value: 1 });
    this.setState({ value: 1 });
    this.setState({ value: 1 });
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
    console.log('updated');
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <p>{this.state.value}</p>
      <button onClick={this.onClickHandler}>RUN TEST</button>
      <p>Please check from Browser Console's Log</p>
    </div>;
  }
}

/*
 * Render the above component into the div#app
 */
React.render(<Application />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: setTimeout does not return a promise that could be awaited.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48731782/2630817 this can be helpful

Comment: Also, setState is itself asynchronous and React will flatten the first three calls if it can.

Comment: @remix23 I know setState is an asynchronous call but why after await it will be triggered every time whenever setState is called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because as [this answer states](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33613918/2131839) React tries to batch `setState` calls and process them together when it can. But this is not the case with asynchronous computations because React (and anybody in general) can't predict and reproduce the order of `setState`'s called asynchronously.

So in your case it fallbacks to just updating state 3 times.

Answer (score 1):

You can got this answer from React.Component life cycle doc (https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

`componentDidUpdate() is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.`

[image: React Component Lifecycle]

Use this method `shouldComponentUpdate()`. This method allows your Component to exit the Update life cycle if there is no reason to apply a new render. Out of the box, the shouldComponentUpdate() is a no-op that returns true. This means every time we start an Update in a Component, we will re-render.

I add more code

```
  shouldComponentUpdate = function(nextProps, nextState) {
    return nextState.value !== this.state.value;
  }

  // Change value will set after await
  runAsyncFunc = async() => {
    console.log('BEFORE AWAIT');
    this.setState({ value: 1 });
    this.setState({ value: 1 });
    this.setState({ value: 1 });

    await setTimeout(()=>{}, 2000);

    console.log('AFTER AWAIT');
    this.setState({ value: 2 });
    this.setState({ value: 2 });
    this.setState({ value: 2 });
  }
```

Check my [Codepen](https://codepen.io/duongtungls/pen/aarOqY)

**So if you want to prevent unnecessary render custom method `shouldComponentUpdate`**

Comment: I wasn't trying to prevent unnecessary render. I just want to know why after await it will trigger componentDidUpdate() whenever setState is called