# Is it possible that this.state has not been updated yet in a handleClick function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[React Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) says

> Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state

Does this mean that i can't trust this.state at any place?

For example:

```js
MyComponent extends Component {
  // ...

  handleClick () {
    // ...
    fetch(targetUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        param1: this.state.param1
      })
    })
  }

  // ...
}
```

Does it mean that i may send wrong param1 to targetUrl(Since this.state may not been updated yet)?

Comment: Nope , state is asynchronous which means for example if you fetch something from an external API , it will send an response so the time taken to get response may be vary !  Thus , according to state , as it's async it's simply goes to other methods instead of waiting till the response comes !  So you can't solely relay on state untill your sure that the response has been received  !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you do when handleClick.

If your `handleClick` method is like this:

```
handleClick () {
    this.setState({ param1: 'something'});
    fetch(targetUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        param1: this.state.param1
      })
    })
  }
```

Then when you call `fetch`, the `this.state.param1` is not updated yet. because `setState` is asynchronous.

And if you don't `setState` in handleClick, then you will be fine with your code.

Read more about `setState` [Beware: React setState is asynchronous!](https://medium.com/@wereHamster/beware-react-setstate-is-asynchronous-ce87ef1a9cf3)

Comment: What confuses me is the second situation. Since both this.setState and handleClick are asynchronous, is it possible that handleClick be called before this.setState? I'll read the article first, thx.

Comment: Do you mean the situation when `handleClick` method gets called repeatedly, then the `setState` gets called continuously and simultaneously, right?

React batches state updates that occur in event handlers and lifecycle methods. Thus, if you update state multiple times in a <div onClick /> handler, React will wait for event handling to finish before re-rendering.

Look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33613918/4327170

Answer (score 1):

set state is asyncchronus . if you want to do something with state like

```
     this.setState({param1:true},()=>{
     fetch(targetUrl, {
     method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({
    param1: this.state.param1
     })
     })
     })
```

it takes a call back where you can get state after state is updated and perform action with the updated one.. hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

It means this.setState({}) updates state asynchronously and not instantly. Reaat will decide when to update the state via this.setState({}).

So if you do this.setState({data: response}), it is not guaranteed that it will state instantly, it might take some time to update it.

You can check this using below code:

```
this.setState({data: response}, () => console.log('state updated'));
```

Above is updating state and when updated it will execute call back method.