# How to call multiple setter functions of useState react hook without re-render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I want to call multiple setter functions together when some event has been triggered.

sth like :

```js
const [running, setRunning] = useState(false);
const [jumping, setJumping] = useState(true);
```

then what should we do, if we want to `setRunning` and `setJumping` together? (avoid re-render component)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can just call them sequentially like this ([demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/q867vno6xj)):

```
const Comp = ({ flag }) => {
  const [running, setRunning] = useState(false);
  const [jumping, setJumping] = useState(false);

  const setBoth = (_e) => {
    setRunning(true);
    setJumping(true);
  };
  
  return (
    <>
      {"running: " + running}
      {"jumping: " + jumping}
      <button onClick={setBoth}>setboth</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

---

Alternatively, you can set them both at the same time like this:

```
const Comp = ({ flag }) => {
  const [RJ, setRJ] = useState([false, false]);

  const setBoth = (_e) => {
    setRJ([true, true]);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {"running: " + RJ[0]}
      {"jumping: " + RJ[1]}
      <button onClick={setBoth}>setboth</button>
    </>
  );
};
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/0pwnm2z94w

Comment: In this way the component will `re-render` twice and I do not want it.

Comment: It will not re-render twice, multiple state changes are batched by React.

Comment: @MikaelLirbank is right ; see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53048495/does-react-batch-state-update-functions-when-using-hooks

Answer (score 0):

This is a great question because it challenges the best practice of having a `setState` for each slice of state.

The best way is to create a POJO with two keys (to be explicit), one for running, one for jumping. Then, the setter will have 3 permutations.

- setting just jumping
- setting just running
- setting both

```
const [actions, setActions] = useState({running: false, jumping: false});
const { jumping, running } = actions;
```

I don't think this is a best practice, you should split them up whenever you can to avoid this pattern. However, this is one instance where it may be worth merging them to save a render (which can be desirable).

Comment: Claiming it will render multiple time is False. "React batches state updates that occur in event handlers and lifecycle methods. Thus, if you update state multiple times in a <div onClick /> handler, React will wait for event handling to finish before re-rendering."

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33613728/what-happens-when-using-this-setstate-multiple-times-in-react-component