# Multiple set state within multiple api call inside componentDidMount in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new in React and trying to call multiple api call within componentDidMount function.

My code is

```
componentDidMount() {

        Promise.all([
            axios.get(<url1>),
            axios.get(<url2>)
            ]).then(([res1, res2]) => {
            // call setState here
            const users =  res1.data.users;
            this.setState({ users: users});
            const banks  =  res2.data.banks;
            this.setState({ banks: banks});
            console.log("Users")
            console.log(users) // It works
            console.log("Banks")
            console.log(banks) // It works
        })

    }

render() {
        console.log(this.state.users.length) // Gives length
        console.log(this.state.banks.length) // Gives undefined
        return (
            <div className='popup'></div>
        )
}
```

The problem is inside render function the second state `banks` length is undefined.

How can I do multiple setstate inside componentDidMount.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Update: Resolved
The mistake was

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        users: [],
        //MISSING BANKS array
    }
}
```

Comment: can you try: `this.setState({ users: users, banks: banks});` instead of two times `setState`

Comment: @Daniel Still undefined

Comment: is `banks` an array? What's the response from your api?

Comment: @Daniel Yes `__proto__: Array(0)` in both cases

Comment: Thanks @Daniel. It works now. My silly mistake as usual. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set state in a single update, updating both values at the same time.  Otherwise you are instructing React to initiate two renders, the first would contain `users` value and an `undefined` value for `banks` (depending on your initial state declaration).  This render would be quickly followed by a second pass, in which both state values `users` and `banks` would be defined.

The below example should work as required, in a single render.

```
Promise.all([
  axios.get(<url1>),
  axios.get(<url2>)
]).then(([res1, res2]) => {
  // call setState here
  const users = res1.data.users;
  const banks = res2.data.banks;
  this.setState({ users, banks });
});
```

On the other hand, if for some strange requirement you actually want two sequential renders you can use `setState`'s done callback; example below.

```
this.setState({ users }, () => {
  this.setState({ banks });
});
```

This will ensure the first render is complete before requesting a new render via setState.

Comment: Maybe there should be a check in the render function as well. Like this.state.banks && this.state.banks.length. If he uses mutliple set states instead of combining one that's probably the reason.

Comment: @Trisma I would suggest it's better to use a default state which contains a valid (empty) structure and this will avoid having ugly conditional logic in render methods.

Comment: That's indeed a better way

Comment: Not necessarily react initiates two renders, please check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33613728/what-happens-when-using-this-setstate-multiple-times-in-react-component  and

Comment: @JonathanMiles Tried both ways but still undefined for banks.

Comment: @SuleymanSah As per the referred answer, wouldn't this be considered an AJAX event handler and therefore not batched.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra Are you sure that banks is a valid Array object, could you response be bad?

Comment: Yes I am quite sure the response is valid array object. I can see in console within axios call. It's the setState which is messing around.

Comment: @PrithvirajMitra Can you put a jsfiddle together to recreate the issue?  Use mock resolved promises

Comment: @JonathanMiles I will try.

Comment: Sorry guys my mistake. I didn't initialize the bank array under constructor. So stupid I am. Please vote me negative, Sorry.

Comment: Updated my original post.