# Only last item is added to array inside map function

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, concatenation

I'm mapping an array inside a map function and I want to add the id of every element inside the array to a state. I'm facing an issue where just the last item is added to the array even though console log shows that the function iterates to correct number of times.

This is the code I have written

```
const { evc } = this.props;
evc.chargingStationGroups && evc.chargingStationGroups.map((item, key) => {
    item.stations.map((stationItem, key) => {
        console.log("stationID ",stationItem.stationID);
        var stationId = {};
        stationId = {
            stationId: stationItem.stationID
        }
        var allIdArray = this.state.stationIdArray.concat(stationId);
        this.setState({ stationIdArray: allIdArray })
    })
})
```

Here `evc.chargingStationGroups` is something like this

```
[
     {
      groupId: "16",
      groupName: "Sia",
      stations: [{stationId: "8", name: "Test"},{stationId: "9", name: "Test2"},{stationId: "10", name: "Test3"}]
     },
     {
      groupId: "17",
      groupName: "Maroon5",
      stations: [{stationId: "10", name: "Test"},{stationId: "11", name: "Test2"},{stationId: "10", name: "Test3"}]
     }
],
```

How can i add all `stationItem.stationID` to my array, not just the last one.

Comment: Do not use `.map` for simple iteration. You are not doing a mapping operation, so it's not the correct tool for the job.

Comment: How else can i add all the stationId to my array?

Comment: are you sure about station10, it seems to be in both groups? do you accept dupplicates in your array?

Comment: If you are unsure what array iteration method is fit for each job, then click on my profile and check my bio. I've written a short guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only call `setState` once inside all your rendering (because `setState` is asynchronous)

Assuming you don't have dupes of station between chargingStationGroups, just concat everybody

```
const { evc } = this.props;
if (evc.chargingStationGroups) {
    const ids = evc.chargingStationGroups.flatMap((item, key) => {
        return item.stations.map((stationItem, key) => {
            return {
                stationId: stationItem.stationID
            }
        })
    })
    const stationIdArray = this.state.stationIdArray.concat(ids)
    this.setState({ stationIdArray })
})
```

Else just avoid the dupes...

```
const { evc } = this.props;
if (evc.chargingStationGroups) {
    const ids = evc.chargingStationGroups.flatMap((item, key) => {
        return item.stations.map((stationItem, key) => {
            return {
                stationId: stationItem.stationID
            }
        })
    })
    const arr = this.state.stationIdArray.concat(ids)
    const s = new Set(arr.map(x => x.stationID))

    const stationIdArray = [...s].map(stationId => ({ stationId }))
    this.setState({ stationIdArray })
})
```

Not tested because no minimal reproducible example given, but you get the idea...

Answer (score 2):

Original answer: [What happens when using this.setState multiple times in React component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33613728/what-happens-when-using-this-setstate-multiple-times-in-react-component)

In brief, `this.setState` is batched and called only once at the end of the loop, leaving `this.state.stationIdArray` empty all the time. Hence only the result at the final iteration of this statement is kept:

```
var allIdArray = this.state.stationIdArray.concat(stationId);
```

Avoid calling `setState` multiple time in this case:

```
const { evc } = this.props;
if (evc.chargingStationGroups) {
  let allIdArray = [];
  evc.chargingStationGroups.forEach(item => {
    allIdArray = [
      ...allIdArray,
      ...item.stations.map(stationItem => ({
        stationId: stationItem.stationId
      }))
    ];
  });
  this.setState({ stationIdArray: allIdArray });
}
```

A simple example: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-swartz-leto5

Comment: Point about batched `setState` use is a really nice catch. Though there's a bit [shorter way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59452046/11299053) to extract nested object prop. However, I think this one is more helpful than accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should just use **forEach** if you want to do operations during iteration.

```
const { evc } = this.props;
evc.chargingStationGroups && evc.chargingStationGroups.forEach((item, key) => {
    item.stations.forEach((stationItem, key) => {
        console.log("stationID ",stationItem.stationID);
        var stationId = {};
        stationId = {
            stationId: stationItem.stationID
        }
        var allIdArray = this.state.stationIdArray.concat(stationId);
        this.setState({ stationIdArray: allIdArray })
    })
})
```