# Update component UI while method is still running - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have an onClick method that loops about 1,000 times before returning, and at the end of each loop, it changes the state. Is there a way to get the component to re-render at the end of each loop as well? I though just updating the state would do it, but that didn't work. I also tried calling `this.forceUpdate()` after updating the state every loop, but that didn't work either. It just does all of the updating all at once after `onClick` returns.

Is there a way to have the component update while the event handler is running?
I am thinking the solution lies in multithreading, but I don't know if there is a better way.

Comment: maybe check this answer out https://stackoverflow.com/a/33613918/2763250 TL;DR `setState` is batched in the react synthetic event handlers

Comment: Why do you want that type of behavior? React batches state updates for performance. What is your exact requirement?

Comment: I'm iteratively adding paths to an SVG element, and I want to animate it because it takes up to a minute to finish

Comment: You should use animation. Check https://www.react-spring.io/ and [this](https://medium.com/@neerajlag/svg-animations-in-react-using-react-spring-78b1f12b46d).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It mostly about [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop). And batching of setState in React.
If you want to animate things https://en.reactjs.org/docs/animation.html