# Update the state of an Array twice in a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In a table i am integrating search functionality based on two parameters based on bank and rate

When i click on Submit i want the set the state of the array to be updated twice first it will initialize will the global array after the results are filtered the updated value should be updated in the state

```
const [fixedDepositNriRates, setFixedDepositNriRates] = useState([]);
const [testData, setTestData] = useState([]);
const SearchResults = () => {
    setFixedDepositNriRates(testData);
    let data = [...fixedDepositNriRates];
    if (bank) {
      data = data.filter(item => item.Group.indexOf(bank) !== -1)
    }
    if (rate) {
      if (rate === 8) {
        data = data.filter(item => item.interest < rate)
      }
      if (rate === 9) {
        data = data.filter(item => item.interest > rate)
      }
      if (rate === 10) {
        data = data.filter(item => item.interest > rate)
      }
    }
    setFixedDepositNriRates(data);
  }
```

I got the filtered result in the variable data but i am not able to set the state as
setFixedDepositNriRates(data);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33613728/what-happens-when-using-this-setstate-multiple-times-in-react-component

Answer (score 1):

The `fixedDepositNriRates` is the result of filtering (if needed) the `testData`. You don't need to clone the `testData`, and then filter and set `fixedDepositNriRates`. Just filter the `testData` before you set it to `fixedDepositNriRates`.

In addition, you can extract the filtering logic to a `filterResults` function, and do the entire filtering in a single step:

```
// outside of the component 
const filterResults = (data, bank, rate) => {
  // don't filter when bank doesn't exist or rate is out of bounds
  if(!bank && (rate < 8 || rate > 10)) return data;
  
  const predicates = [];
  
  // populate the list of conditions
  if(bank) predicates.push(item => item.Group.includes(bank));
  if(rate === 8) predicates.push(item => item.interest < rate);
  else if(rate > 8) predicates.push(item => item.interest > rate);
  
  // filter and apply all conditions
  return data.filter(item => predicates.every(predicate => 
    predicate(item)
  )));
}

// inside the component

const [fixedDepositNriRates, setFixedDepositNriRates] = useState([]);
const [testData, setTestData] = useState([]);

const SearchResults = () => {
  setFixedDepositNriRates(filterResults(testData, bank, rate));
}
```

Comment: This. +1 for list of predicates combined with every.