# How do I clear states or empty array on click in react 0.14 ES6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, ecmascript-6

I am rendering an array in a modal. Once the modal closes I need to empty the array.The following code updates the array but not clear array on click of closeModal.

```
constructor(props,context) {
   super(props,context);
   this.state = {
      myArray: []
   };

 }

 pushData(newVar) {
   this.setState((state) => {
       myArray: state.myArray.push(newVar)
   });
 }

 closeModal() {
   this.setState({
       myArray: []
   })
 }
```

Comment: Something like this.state.myarray=[]

Comment: Hey Sorry you are right @Antonio this.state.myarray=[]  fixed my problem.

Comment: Push data seems weird... I would write this.state.myArray.push(newVar)

Comment: this.state.myArray.push(newVar) this way of pushing didnt work for me. I tried .concat too but didnt work

Comment: Are you getting an error? It's not clear what's broken from your question. What does your `render` function look like?

Comment: Sorry for the trouble given I found out the closeModal didnt get called at all on componentWillUnmount. So i Changed it back to my old code and fixed it this.setState({myArray: []}); will work.

Comment: `state.myArray.push(newVar)` will not behave as expected either. `Array.prototype.push` returns the length of the new array, not the array with the new value in it. `setState(state => ({myArray: state.myArray.concat(newVar)}))` is closer to what you're looking for.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I found the problem is my closeModal didn’t get called at all on closing modal. I am doing that to closeModal on componentWillUnmount function.
I understood that the below code causes problem.

```
this.state.myArray=[] // class component
const[myArray, setMyArray]=useState([]) // functional component
```

I changed it back to

```
this.setState({myArray: []}); // class component
setMyArray([]); // functional component
```

Comment: _Never_ assign to `this.state` outside of the constructor. That might fix your immediate problem but it _will_ cause bugs.

Comment: Yes, use `this.setState({ myArray: [] });` instead.

Answer (score 5):

You can as well use this to clear array without using setState:

```
   this.state.your_array.length = 0;
```

This will work in any function.

**Update**
Functional component:

```
   setYourArray([])
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of solutions with explanations to this (albeit in ES5) can be found here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29994490/4572987

Comment: So the pushData method correctly adds newVar into the state and causes a re-render correct? why not make those methods uniform and have closeModal look like:     this.setState((state) => {
       myArray: []
   });

Comment: If that doesn't work, I suspect it has something to do with the code changing the actual reference React has to the myArray variable, and as a result not affecting it at all..

Answer (score 1):

```
this.state.array.splice();
```

This will Delete or truncate whole array

Comment: This will not update the state, also splice needs two params:

1. start The zero-based location in the array from which to start removing
2. deleteCount The number of elements to remove

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me. 
Class based component

```
this.setState({myArray: []});
```

With React Hook,

```
const [myArray, setMayArray] = React.useState([]);
setMayArray([]);
```